# How to custom format date-time String into a GMT Date object?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, time, java-8

I have a couple of data feeds that provide me a date-time string with different formats representing local date and time.

I've come with this solution:

```
    String dateString = "2010-12-01 5:00";
    String datePattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm";
    String timeZone = "Europe/Paris";

    try {

        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(datePattern);
                         dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(timeZone));

        Instant instant =
            dateFormat
                .parse(dateString)
                .toInstant();

        Date date = Date.from(instant);

        System.out.println(date.toString());

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I'm using Java8 with SpringBoot. Is there a faster/simple approach ?

Comment: Ok, so I presume your solution doesn't do what you expected? What result did you expect, and how does the actual result differ from what you expected? Note that a `java.util.Date` object does not have a timezone in itself. When you do `date.toString()` it will always be formatted in the default timezone of your system. (There's no such thing as a "Date object in the GMT timezone", because the Date object doesn't contain timezone information).

Comment: The problem is actually that with this piece of code my service is 20x times slower. I've previously try an hardcoded instant.plus(60, ChronoUnit.MINUTES).toInstant()  to avoid using dateFormat.setTimeZone() and I obtain the same result without any delay.

Comment: Did you try java 8 data-time api (ZonedDateTime)? [java-8-date-time-intro](https://www.baeldung.com/java-8-date-time-intro)

Comment: Tx @Jasper, this was actually another problem solved a while ago, and i just found the "solution" -> `TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"))`. I guess i have to do a proper refactor.